# Building a To-Do List with jQuery and Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi i am working on a project to do task list where every thing work fine but i am not able to store data in list in following link data is store in

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoData"));

But i want to save it in list so different people access and update data from different browser , following is the link of code

http://www.sitepoint.com/building-list-jquery-local-storage/

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by a "list"?  a sharepoint list? you can use JSOM or rest API to store information into sharepoint lists.

[more information is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)